# Configure postfix for external SMTP

Tags: dns, smtp, postfix

I have a PC at home with Manjaro, connected to the internet through a MODEM that an "internet service provider" has installed for me, from which optical fiber goes out to the world.
My connection is DNS (I don't have a fixed IP)
The issue is that I am confused by all the literature on how to configure postfix to send mail through the SMTP server that my "internet service provider" has.
Specifically, mydomain confuses me (I don't have a domain. What do I put there? My SMTP domain?) Mynetworks (it's a "standalone" PC) myorigin? localhost? I think that bounces me off!
Nor do I know whether to use the aliases file, or the canonical or the generic or more than one?
Third, the user in MIPC is not the same as the user I have in external SMTP.
I have been 2 days reading and testing and all the emails bounce me from the SMTP
In the many tests I have done, I have seen that sometimes in email it comes out with the MIPC username, not with the user registered in the SMTP, or it does not return to the postmaster because it thinks to find the postmaster in the external SMTP domain, etc.
In short, I can not configure it and make it work

Specifically, I want to use:
SMTP server: vera.com.uy
There I have a mailbox (a user and a password)
Help!!!